# reload the form with a button in access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form (edit only form). It has an **OnLoad event** that will show only a **combobox** for the user to choose from, which then by an **AfterUpdate event** will show some controls in the form, through visible and enable properties of the controls. Then the user can click a button to save the dirty record by this code:

```
    If Me.Dirty Then
          Me.Dirty = False
    End If
```

Till here everything is ok.

What I need is with the same button click event, the form to reload to its original status, i.e. to reload the form as if it is closed and re-opened like the previous **OnLoad event** to show only my **combobox**

I tried the requery and refresh methods, but that does not bring me back to the **OnLoad event** shape.

Comment: Requery or refresh methods of form do not change ``visible`` property of controls. You can set focus on Combobox and  set ``visible`` property of controls, except first ComboBox, by example, in save button event sub. MyOtherControl.visible=false.

Comment: Consider leaving all controls visible and using Conditional Formatting to enable/disable textboxes and comboboxes. Only enable when main combobox has value. No VBA needed. Otherwise, expand code in button Click or try OnCurrent event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to abstract your code by putting logic into a separate sub.

Instead of

```
Sub MyCombo_AfterUpdate()
    Me!foo.Visible = True
    Me!bar.Enabled = True
    ' etc.
End Sub
```

create a sub for this:

```
Sub ShowEditControls(bShow As Boolean)
    Me!foo.Visible = bShow 
    Me!bar.Enabled = bShow 
    ' etc.
End Sub
```

and then simply

```
Sub MyCombo_AfterUpdate()
    ShowEditControls True
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub btSave_Click()
    If Me.Dirty Then
          Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    Me!MyCombo.SetFocus
    Me!MyCombo.Value = Null   ' or whatever initial value you need

    ShowEditControls False
End Sub
```